# Can't get Grub to handle booting, Windows boot manager keeps taking control

Tags: linux, grub2

I have Windows 8 and Liunx Mint installed and can only boot to Mint by overriding the boot order through the UEFI.

I'm using an HP laptop that has a garbage firmware interface so I can't set it to boot by a specific OS on startup, only when I'm doing an override at boot. That at least would give me a temporary fix.

I've disabled secure boot, turned off fast boot, ran boot repair, and used BCDedit to change the Windows boot device to grub64.efi. Also tried shimx64.efi. I set Grub to boot Mint by default as well.

Can't find any other suggestions through Google. Any ideas?

Comment: i guess you already know about these instructions here? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue seems built into the HP UEFI/BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file) - it will only accept a /Microsoft folder for boot. Having had this issue on a HP laptop, [and having tried a number of fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554690/hp-uefi-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-automatically), I finally just **replaced** the Windows boot EFI file with the Linux version:

- Make an image of the HDD lest something go wrong.
- Move the MS boot file, `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, to an new folder, e.g. `/boot/efi/EFI/old-Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`
- Copy the contents of `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` (or `grubx64.efi`) to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/`.
- Rename `shimx64.efi` (or `grubx64.efi`) to `bootmgfw.efi`.
- Change the path for the `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi` entry in grub to the location of the MS boot file, e.g. `/boot/efi/EFI/old-Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. [Thanks to @BrainRenticus for reminding me of this essential step!]

This should now consistently boot to the grub menu (though I got rid of dual boot, since Ubuntu was so much faster on the laptop).

Assuming you did not disable Secure Boot permanently (e.g. by installing third-party drivers), you can revert that and other UEFI settings. BTW, you might want a hard copy of this procedure -- Windows updates frequently mess with the boot loader (another reason I dropped Windows).

Comment: Note that while this solution does work, you will have to do it again every time you update to a new build of Windows (that is, going through what Microsoft calls a 'Feature Update'), because the bootloader will get overwritten during such updates.

Comment: True... on the HP in question, I finally got rid of Windows to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pippik, i was ready to put this problem on the shelf for awhile. For anyone else with this issue I also had to change the path for the "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" entry in grub to a copy of the original (real) bootmgfw.efi file i placed in a different directory. Otherwise youll do an endless grub loop when trying to boot to windows.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the reminder on that essential step, if dual boot is to work.